# sending value with link with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, parameter-passing

I am viewing the content of mysql inbox_messages table and view every message as link to reply the message or delete . so i have to send the message id with the link to specify the message in the editing page the code was

```
<a href="sompage.php?m_id=<? echo $m_id; ?>" >
```

and it's working.
But when I tried to make it with javascript to make the reply like chat box i dont know how to send the message id while opening and to get the id with php  and i am opening the message in a div with this code

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)"  
   class="display" 
   onclick = "document.getElementById('responsecontainer').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" 
   style="font-weight:normal;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="sompage.php?m_id=<? echo $m_id; ?>" >`
can be replaced by appending `?m_id=` and a variable equal to whatever `$m_id` is.

Example:

```
var m_id = <?php $M_id ?>;
var yourLink = document.getElementById("replyLink");
yourLink.href = yourLink.href+"?m_id="+m_id;
```

That said, getting `$m_id` into the javascript without inline PHP in a synchronous manner would probably require the use of GET parameters, which is another topic, so I'll just give you a helpful link to get started:
http://javascriptproductivity.blogspot.com/2013/02/get-url-variables-with-javascript.html